# What is this second smaller runway next to London City Airport?

Tags: airport, uk

I was looking at London City Airport (EGLC) on Google Maps today when I noticed the remains of a very small runway marked 10/28 just across the water from City Airport's main runway. It can be seen [here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/51%C2%B030'26.1%22N+0%C2%B003'32.5%22E/@51.507235,0.0573593,536m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x0:0x0!7e2!8m2!3d51.5072353!4d0.0590342).

To my surprise I couldn't find any mention of this small runway after searching online and looking into the history of the airport. Using the Google Earth historical imagery feature the earliest image I could find that included the runway was 2008, so I assume it was built some time between 2006 and 2008.

Can anybody tell me what this short runway is for?

Comment: God! Nice shot! I admire you being able to spot things like this! :>

Comment: It hasn't got the usual X for a closed runway?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Good Spot! That was a temporary runway for the Red Bull Air Race:

https://www.forgottenairfields.com/airfield-london-redbull-airstrip-1429.html

You can see "RB" at the eastern end on your satellite imagery

Comment: According to the [English wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Bull_Air_Race_World_Championship#Race_locations) the River Thames was used as a race location for the 6th round on [July 29 in 2007](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2007_Red_Bull_Air_Race_World_Series#Race_calendar) and for the 5th round on [August 2 and 3 in 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_Red_Bull_Air_Race_World_Series#Race_calendar_and_results).

Comment: 12 years on and that's looking like it's in pretty rough shape already.

Comment: The page says London City was closed during the race anyway, which makes me wonder why they didn't simply use it.

Comment: @JanHudec Maybe because of LCY's rule: _steep approach and steep prices_ ;-)